# Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated `Android Studio to 2.3` recently. When I try to open existing project which was running in AS 2.2 giving me below error in gradle:

> Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.AlwaysRedirectRedirectStrategy

When I restart AS it show's below error

```
Error:Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory'.
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

My project gradle is :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Module level gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'asda'
            keyPassword 'asdas'
            storeFile file('/home/.playstore/asda/asd.jks')
            storePassword 'asda'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //shrinkResources true
            //minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
            exclude module: "httpclient"
        }
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
        compile 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:1.3'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your both `gradle`, project's and app's.

Comment: Is your "Android Support Repository" installed?

Comment: Yes, its installed.

Comment: `Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)` - You should try out re-downloading dependencies.

Comment: When trying to download its again showing above mentioned error. I tried re-installing AS again after uninstalling all files and directories.